# Firebase App Distribution for Android from gradle with groups totalling more than 200 users

Tags: android, gradle, firebase-app-distribution

I just migrated my Android app from `Fabric Beta` to `Firebase App Distribution`. My `Fabric` group `android` had `395` people in it, and `Firebase` only allows a maximum of `200` people in a group, so I split my `Firebase` groups into `android-1` and `android-2`.

Here is my gradle definition:

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
  releaseNotes="Alpha"
  groups="android-1, android-2, qa"
}
```

However, when I try to run my gradle task, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:appDistributionUploadRelease'.
> App Distribution halted because it had a problem adding testers/groups: [400] Request contains an invalid argument.
```

If I change `groups` to:

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
  releaseNotes="Alpha"
  groups="android-1, qa"
}
```

or:

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
  releaseNotes="Alpha"
  groups="android-2, qa"
}
```

everything works fine.

I suspect that firebase just doesn't want to send more than `200` emails at a time when there's a new update.
Does anyone have an idea how to work around this?

Also, I'm trying to find the github project for this, so I can file an issue, but nothing is coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A firebase developer relations engineer told me this is likely a Firebase Bug. I submitted a bug report there. I'll update this answer when I learn more.

**Update**

Someone from [`firebase-community`](https://firebase-community.slack.com/archives/CRS1Q7DRT/p1582296499007700) showed me [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/manage-testers#tester-limits) proving that `Firebase App Distribution` is limited to `200` users:

> *Tester limits*
>   App Distribution offers free quotas that let you start distributing your app at no cost. The free quota amounts are listed below. If you need more quota, request a free [limit increase](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScnnQA3toZsLWHfMWkjppYS4n0pR526d0_K8eufFDufAWj06A/viewform).
>
> ||Operation||Quota||
>
> |Add testers to a Firebase project|500 testers per Firebase project|
>
> |Add testers to an App Distribution group|200 testers per group|
>
> |Distribute to testers|200 testers per build distribution|

Comment: If this is a bad answer, please add a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received above error when I had

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
    appId = "1:sdsdsdsdsdsds:android:blablabla"
    testers="abc1@pqr.com abc2@pqr.com abc3@pqr.com"
}
```

I created a group on Firebase called QA and I changed my build.gradle to

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
    appId = "1:sdsdsdsdsdsds:android:blablabla"
    groups="QA"
}
```

and it worked. I still have no clue why one works and other does not every signle time.

Comment: You missed the comma separating each email address